# How to solve the "overscan" issue if the iMac is connected to an HDTV and using BootCamp and Windows 7?

Tags: displayport, hdmi, television

This question is related to both iMac and Windows, but since it is happening on an iMac 27 inch model, so I hope posting in the Apple forum is more relevant.

Basically, when an iMac is connected to an HDTV, part of the screen is missing near the margin (about 3% to 5%).  If running Mac OS X, the issue can be solved by using "underscan" in the System Preferences.  But what if the iMac is running Windows 7, can a similar solution be used?  (I don't see such options for the graphics card...).

(The solution of the iMac if running OS X is: [How to solve Mini DisplayPort to HDMI Overscan problem? (Part of the screen is missing)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30527/how-to-solve-mini-displayport-to-hdmi-overscan-problem-part-of-the-screen-is-m) )

Comment: For others: a good explanation of the overscan issue:  http://hd.engadget.com/2010/05/27/hd-101-overscan-and-why-all-tvs-do-it/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need to have a software solution within Windows?  Many HDTVs let you adjust current display settings to disable the overscan.  See [PCWorld - Tech Trend: For HDTV, Don't Overlook Overscan](http://www.pcworld.com/article/145155/tech_trend_for_hdtv_dont_overlook_overscan.html).  Quote:

> If you don't see every pixel you should see, you're not viewing a true
>   1920 by 1080 progressive-scan picture. The name of the viewing mode
>   differs from brand to brand, but it's commonly called Dot-by-Dot,
>   Point-to-Point, Just, or simply Overscan Off.

To add to that, on my own HDTV, choosing **"Studio"** under the Aspect setting has the effect of eliminating the overscan.  I've also seen it called simply "PC" on another TV, and "Just Scan" on another.

Check your HDTV's settings ... chances are it has something like this and you aren't aware of it.  Though, admittedly there are some HDTVs without such a capability (sadly) and for these you'll need to find a solution that lets you reduce the resolution output to the HDTV.

**Update:** I found the following article explains well both the issue and troubleshooting steps: [Windows Experts Community - Configure Your Display and Display Adapter](http://experts.windows.com/w/experts_wiki/configure-your-display-and-display-adapter.aspx).

Plus: some folks have successfully replaced the Apple video drivers in their Bootcamp Windows with ATI drivers, **in order to access settings to compensate for the HDTV overscan**.  See this blog post: [Apple Macbook Pro (Early 2011) running Bootcamp Windows 7 with ATI / AMD Catalyst Control Center](http://andrew.stannard.name/blog/2011/10/02/apple-macbok-pro-early-2011-running-bootcamp-windows-7-with-ati-amd-catalyst-control-center/).  Got ATI video in your Mac?  Worth a shot perhaps, if you do.  Take a backup before messing with drivers, of course.

Comment: Interesting... my Samsung series 6 40 inch HDTV has a setting that's called "Just Scan"... and another setting which is "16:9".   The "16:9" will overscan, and the "Just Scan" will not...

Comment: So "Just Scan" worked for you? If so, that's better than adjusting the video output from the computer to compensate (last thing I just pointed to in my updated answer). Maybe on the Mac side you can turn off the underscan now and use the full TV res with no issue?

Comment: Yes on OS X, I can also remove the "underscan" in the System Preferences once the "Just Scan" is selected on the HDTV.  That should be a better solution because then the computer doesn't need to first underscan (make it smaller size) and then let the HDTV overscan (make it bigger size).  "Just Scan" can show the original picture pixel by pixel without any resizing.